# Running multiple 'instances' of maven project - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, netbeans

I am trying to run multiple instances of the same maven project using netbeans. There is only 1 main class in the project.
This is the error I get:

---

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project Client: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\x\x\x\Client\target\Client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

---

I realise that I cannot run more than one instances because maven cannot clean/delete the jar file while it is already in use. However, I need to get this working; to implement and test multi-threading and synchronisation.

Anyone know a solution or a workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you like to run the build in parallel for the same project? Just build once `mvn clean package` and start your resulting jar several times via ` java -jar ...target/Client-1.0-SNAPSHTO.jar` from different console windows...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can't believe I missed that simple solution, thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you like to run the build in parallel for the same project? Just build once `mvn clean package` and start your resulting jar several times via `java -jar ...target/Client-1.0-SNAPSHTO.jar` from different console windows.